# Visual Studio 2017 WiX project pre-build event - does not execute all batch commands

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2017

My WiX project has a pre-build event: running a bat file. The commands in the bat file get executed only to line 29. Later commands don't execute. There is no error.

The build process continues after executing half of the bat commands. Swapping lines 29 and 30 doesn't change anything - execution still stops at line 29. Adding an empty line before line 29 shifts the end of execution to line 30. Removing all blank lines shifts the end to line 25.

When running outside Visual Studio, the batch file executes all commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround was to use PowerShell to execute the batch file. The build event looks like this now:

```
powershell prebuild.bat
```

The problem is caused by another process that attaches to cmd and causes it to crash with error 5. The specific line number of the last executed command depends on timing.